# SNMP Bandwidth Monitoring - Billion Router

Tags: networking, monitoring, bandwidth, network-monitoring, snmp

I have several sites around the country, all sites are using the Billiion BiPAC 7402GX router.

I need to setup bandwidth monitoring tools to allow me to see the sites visitied, amount of bandwith up and down, traffic volume over specific ports etc.

If possible, I would like them to send me daily emails containing the reports.

If that is not possible, I am happy to setup a centailized server that the individual sites can publish their reports to.

Is there such a tool like this?

Thanks

Ian

Comment: wish we had some more people reply to this too... i was hoping to find a program, that doesn't require PERL or something extra to be installed. Just a .NET app would be uber sweet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using snmp, you might get more information out of netflows.  If your device can't generate netflows, you can generate your own if you can port-mirror the interesting interface on your router (presumably, the inside or trust interface).

[Here are my notes on installing fprobe and nfsen](http://wiki.xdroop.com/space/Linux/Installing+nfsen), which in this configuration generates and then analyzes netflow information.

However you still won't be able to get specific target URL information out of this configuration.  For that you need a proxy or some software that reads the network stream and can pick URLs out of the passing requests.  (If anyone knows of such software, I would be very interested in hearing about it!)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/), the PHP SNMP monitoring web tool, which could simply management of several devices and corresponding graphs/reports.

In terms of customising a template for the router you're using have a look at [this forum posting](http://forums.cacti.net/about19757.html) to get ideas.

Comment: Note, it will take you a long time to figure out how to set up Cacti just the way you need/want; be prepared to spend a lot of time on this project!

Answer (score 0):

Given that particular broadband router supports SNMP v3 MIB-I/II you could script something to give you some of what you're looking for.

That said I'm not sure that the router, in particular that level of router, is where you should be doing that kind of work; traditionally you'd measure those metrics from a proxy or firewall - they're built to do that sort of thing.

Oh and if you do choose to go for this via the router be aware that the reporting data itself will be counted in the information the router is handling so remember to discount it or it'll throw your stats.